# node / react after installing .env module, error for "fs"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables

I need to read some environmental variables on my node/react project.

After I installed **dotenv**

> npm install dotenv --save

I import dotenv in my js file:

> require('dotenv').config();

then I get an error for "fs"

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/Na/projects/laa/node_modules/dotenv/lib'
```

So, is this because "file system" is not installed?

how to fix it?

cheers

Comment: Looks like yes. dotenv reads config from path so you need to install file system as well npm i -s fs

Comment: Try adding this following to your webpack config `node: {fs: "empty"}`

Comment: the dotenv is for the Node back-end or the react front end?

Answer (score 3):

For the latest releases, you don't need the **dotenv** module any more. Environment variables are available with **react-scripts@0.2.3 and higher**.
According to [**Create React App** docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/):

> Environment Variables is available with react-scripts@0.2.3 and higher.

So the only thing you need to do is to create the .env file and put your variables in it with the prefix **REACT_APP_{your variable name}**, and then you can use any variable in your code using:

```
process.env.REACT_APP_{your variable name}
```